# Simple machine learning task not working

Tags: python, regression, gradient

Following Siraj's demo: here is my code for a line of best fit for single variable data

(files can be found [here](https://github.com/llSourcell/linear_regression_demo)):

```
#import dependencies
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read data
dataframe = pd.read_fwf('brain_body.txt')
x_values = dataframe[['Brain']]
y_values = dataframe[['Body']]

#train model on data
body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_values, y_values)

#visualize results
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values)
plt.plot(x_values, body_reg.predict(x_values))
plt.show()
```

**I keep getting this mess:**

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mine looks identical. Came here to see if anyone had posted some help. The issue appears to be something with the 2 outliers (2547-4603, and 6654-5712) as these are significantly higher.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Darren O'Rourke for his answer

Since there seems to be a difference in pandas library, numpy solved the problem for me.

```
import numpy as np
x_values = np.array(x_values)
y_values = np.array(y_values)﻿
```

I hope this solves the problem.

Cheers